# Sort a text file by line length including spaces

Tags: c

I want to write a program that reads the lines in a text file and sorts them by length. After reading the file, I want to output the contents into the command line and an output file. I also want to use the text files as arguments of the command-line.

These are my created sentences for trials

```
1. hello world
2. john doe at the bay watch
3. Great Heavens
4. altair
5. Jim and Jamy
```

my source.c

```
int main(void) {

    FILE* fread = fopen("C:\\Users\\Peter\\desktop\\input.txt", "r");
    FILE* fwrite = fopen("C:\\Users\\Peter\\desktop\\output.txt", "w");

    if (fread == NULL || fwrite == NULL) {
        printf("One file wouldn't open!\n");
        return -1;
    }

        //(1.) this copies the text from input.txt to output.txt
    char c; 
    while ((c = fgetc(fread)) != EOF) {
        fputc(c, fwrite);
    }


        //(2.) this pastes the text from input.txt into the command-line
    char line[1000] = "";
    while (fscanf(fread, "%s", line) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }

    fclose(fread);
    fclose(fwrite);

}
```

Results

- output.txt

```
1. hello world
2. john doe at the bay watch
3. Great Heavens
4. altair
5. Jim and Jamy
```

- terminal / command-line

```
1.
hello
world
2.
john
doe
at
the
bay
watch
3.
Great
Heavens
4.
altair
5.
Jim
and
Jamy
```

My problems are:

1. For (1.) and (2.) only one works at the time. so if I switch them around the other one doesn't work anymore
2. The command-line ignores spaces and uses that as a new line
3. I wouldn't know how to sort the strings by length (1-2-3-4-5 into 2-3-5-1-4)
4. Pasting the second order in the output.txt file and the command-line at the same time

Comment: Did you read the description of the effect of white space on `"%s"`? There are other format string elements for the scanf-family which might help you. Or different functions with the explicit purpose to read whole lines.

Comment: After you have read the input file the first time, you need to "go back to start of file" before you can read it again. For instance by closing the file and open it again. Or you can look at `rewind` or `fseek` functions. **BUT**... why read the file twice? Just read it once and store the lines in memory

Comment: When reading **lines** I recommend you take a look at `fgets`

Comment: For sorting.... Save the lines in an array (e.g. an array of char pointers to dynamic allocated memory that holds the strings). The use qsort for sorting.

Comment: A simple `qsort` example: https://ideone.com/Ho0miU